Redirección API Gateway
Tengo un problema con una app que estoy desarrollando en arquitectura de microservicios.
Dicha app se compone por un servicio-1 y un gateway.
Actualmente, el servicio-1 tiene el siguiente controlador:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service-1")
public class Service1Controller {

    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("El endpoint test funciona correctamente");
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/test2")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test2(@Valid Request request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("El endpoint test2 funciona correctamente");
    }
}

El servicio gateway, tiene parametrizado en el application.yml la ruta al anterior servicio:
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: service-1
          uri: http://localhost:8021
          predicates:
            - Path=/service-1/**

Y tiene la siguiente dependencia:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>

Esto funciona correctamente, cuando pruebo cualquiera de las dos peticiones desde el Postman, llamando al gateway, sabe redirigir correctamente al service-1 y me devuelve los resultados esperados.
OK => POST: http://localhost:8080/service-1/test
OK => POST: http://localhost:8080/service-1/test2 (con los datos del request)

Hasta aquí todo correcto, como tengo sólo un servicio en local es factible mantener la configuración en el application.yml, pero como quiero meter más servicios, y no tengo pensado que funcione en local (para hacer pruebas y programarlo vale, pero luego quería pasarlo a otra máquina con docker) he querido implementar el auto-descubrimiento. La primera opción que he encontrado es Eureka (desconozco si hay otras opciones mejores).
Por el tutorial que he seguido, he tenido que definir un nuevo servicio para Eureka, actualizando el archivo de aplicación con la etiqueta @EnableEurekaServer y actualizando el archivo de propiedades:
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=eureka-server

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

A este proyecto le he añadido la dependencia:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

Eureka me obliga a modificar mi actual servicio (service-1), añadiendo la etiqueta @EnableDiscoveryClient a la clase aplicación, y añadiendo lo siguiente en el archivo de propiedades:
server.port=8021
spring.application.name=service-a

eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

Le he añadido la siguiente dependencia:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

Y ahora los cambios de mi gateway. En la clase de aplicación he añadido la etiqueta @EnableDiscoveryClient, el archivo de propiedades ha quedado de la siguiente forma:
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true

y tengo las siguientes dependencias:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

Básicamente he eliminado las rutas de la configuración porque el auto-descubrimiento debe añadirlas.
Si vuelvo a probar las dos peticiones anteriores, ahora me dan error, dice que no las encuentra:
KO => POST: http://localhost:8080/service-1/test
KO => POST: http://localhost:8080/service-1/test2 (con los datos del request)

pero si las llamo directamente al servicio, funcionan bien
OK => POST: http://localhost:8021/service-1/test
OK => POST: http://localhost:8021/service-1/test2 (con los datos del request)

Esto me hace pensar que Eureka no está bien configurado, porque en el postman, me da error 404 al buscar /test y /test2. Con este error, y a modo de prueba, he definido un segundo controlador en el proyecto service1:
@RestController
public class Service1Controller2 {

    @PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("El endpoint (sin mapping) test funciona correctamente");
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/test2")
    public ResponseEntity<String> test2(@Valid Request request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("El endpoint (sin mapping) test2 funciona correctamente");
    }
}

Ahora, cuando ejecuto http://localhost:8080/service-1/test me devuelve el mensaje "El endpoint (sin mapping) test funciona correctamente", lo que me hace pensar que al haber configurado Eureka en el gateway hay algo que hace que se pierda la ruta que coincide con el identificador del servicio.
Por otro lado, al ejecutar http://localhost:8080/service-1/test2 me devuelve error, porque ahora el gateway no es capaz de redirigir la petición completa (no se envía el request).
Después de este libro, tengo las siguientes preguntas:

Al configurar el Gateway con auto-descubrimiento por Eureka, cuando se reenvían las peticiones, ¿se puede mantener el prefijo o el nombre del servicio?
¿Cómo puedo lograr que el Gateway con la nueva configuración pueda enviar los datos que llegan en la cabecera original?, de tal modo que si envío un parámetro, pueda llegarle a mi servicio destino

Gracias de antemano
